# What's the best practice to write "e && e.preventDefault()" to pass JsLint?

Tags: javascript, jslint

When use `e && e.preventDefault()`, JsLint will throw the following error.

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

How can I change the code to pass JsLint, but still keep the code simple?

Comment: Pass JsLint or rewrite code/disable checks, choose one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this passes jslint.

```
function handler(e) {
    "use strict";
    if (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Not sure the community as a whole agrees with this particular jslint rule, but to answer your question directly, use the syntax above. That's my simplest version I could devise that jslint would bless as supremely holy and kosher.

Comment: If you would like to make it smaller (and still get JSLint approval) use this: if (e) { e.preventDefault(); }